# DFS from explicit to implicit stack problem

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

I've been trying to learn DFS, and I have two algorithms below called dfs and dfs2. I originally wrote dfs using a stack without recursion then tried to translate it using recursion without an explicit stack data structure, but the two methods are producing different outputs for this case (27 and 15 respectively) and I don't understand why.

```
import java.util.*;

class zz {
    private static final int n = 40;
    private static int best = 0;
    private static boolean[][] connected;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        connected = new boolean[][]{
                {true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, true, false, false},
                {false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {true, false, false, true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {true, false, false, false, false, true, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {true, false, false, false, false, true, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, true, false, false, true, false, false, false, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {true, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}, 
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}, 
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}, 
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}, 
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false},
                {false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, true, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true}
        };

        dfs2(3, 0, new boolean[n]);
        System.out.println(dfs(3) + " " + best);
    }

    private static int dfs(int i) {
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[n];

        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.add(i);

        int count = 0;
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            int j = stack.pop();

            if (!visited[j]) {
                visited[j] = true;

                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    if (connected[j][k]) {
                        count++;
                        stack.add(k);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    private static void dfs2(int i, int count, boolean[] visited) {
        if (visited[i]) {
            return;
        }

        visited[i] = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (connected[i][j]) {
                count++;
                best = Math.max(best, count);
                dfs2(j, count, visited);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dfs2, the problem is that once the implicit stack is getting popped and another connected node is found, the global variable best does not get updated properly. After the stack is full and then a pop occurs for an earlier node, variable count returns to a lower value and that value gets incremented, instead of the highest value of count at the point when the stack was at its max size.